# Is there an equivalent of Rindler coordinates for an object in centripetal motion?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, centripetal-force, unruh-effect

Rindler coordinates are a parametrization of (a subset of) Minkowski space that are "natural" for an object experiencing constant acceleration - more specifically, an object experiencing constant acceleration parallel to its velocity. Centripetal motion is of course the related case where the object's acceleration is perpendicular to its velocity. Is there an equivalent natural set of coordinates for this case? If there is, is it trivial (i.e. no different than polar coordinates for Minkowski space)? I'm also wondering if there is an equivalent of the Unruh effect.

A starting point: I went through some of the initial derivation, and (unless I'm mistaken) here are some results. Assuming an ansatz circular path for the object in Minkowski space of radius $R$ and tangential velocity $v$, it works out that the object's acceleration in it's local frame is (in units where c = 1)
$$
 a = - \hat r \cdot \frac{d^2 \vec x}{dt'^2} = \frac{1}{1-v^2} \frac{v^2}{R} = \gamma^2 \frac{v^2}{R}.
$$
The proper time of the object in motion is, of course, $\tau = t/\gamma$. That this is independent of $x$, unlike the case in Rindler coordinates where $\tau = a^{-1} \arctan(t/x)$, makes me think that the end result might be trivial, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you want a coordinate system for something like a single observer moving around the rim of a disc (which is circular in the inertial frame of the center of the disc), without the requirement that the disc be circular in the observer's own non-inertial frame? (maybe just using the disc's shape in the instantaneous comoving inertial frame?) Or do you want something more like a traditional rotating frame, where if we had a bunch of observers traveling around the disc at the same angular velocity, in the new non-inertial frame they would all be at rest and at equal distance from the center?

Comment: If the latter, I found [this pdf](http://www.projects.science.uu.nl/igg/dieks/rotation.pdf) on rotating frames in flat spacetime which looks helpful.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I believe my question regards the former, though I think that the latter is interesting and I am consulting the pdf (thank you for the link). Perhaps I'll learn that the latter is more in line with the spirit of the question.

Comment: Do you also want a system that's similar to Rindler coordinates in these two respects? 1) The difference in time coordinates between events on the observer's worldline should be proportional to the proper time between them along that worldline. 2) At any given point on the observer's worldline, the definition of simultaneity should match that of the observer's instantaneous comoving inertial frame at that point, and distances to other points in that simultaneity surface should be proportional to distances in the comoving frame too.

Comment: This third definition is probably the closest. Also, it seems like the first two coordinate systems from your first post are probably just related by a translatio

Comment: What do you mean by "first two coordinate systems"? Are you comparing a hypothetical non-inertial coordinate system for a "single observer moving around the rim of the disc" (which I was actually thinking would be one that satisfied conditions 1 and 2 from my most recent comment, although I didn't spell it out) with the type of rotating frame discussed in the pdf where multiple different rotating observers are at rest and at the same radius? Or are you comparing it to the instantaneous comoving frame I mentioned in the middle of that first comment?

Comment: The following is an extremely good reference on uniform circular motion in SR, see if it fits the bill and if it doesn't then a more detailed description of what it is you want would be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_coordinates

Comment: @Hypnosifl By "first two" I did mean "rim of disk" and "traditional rotating frame" from your first comment, sorry for being sloppy. (And I think my guess that the relationship between the two is a simple translation was wrong.)

Comment: @FenderLesPaul Thank you; I will consult this as well as the pdf Hypnosifl linked to. These Born coordinates sound like Hypnosifl's description of a non-inertial coordinate system for a single observer moving around a disk, and perhaps they satisfy conditions 1) and 2) that Hypnosifl suggested.