# Unruh radiation in a rotating frame

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, unruh-effect

Unruh radiation normally applies to linearly accelerated frames

Is there an equivalent of the Unruh thermal radiation in a frame that is spinning? I am not aware of any horizon being created from a spinning frame, so I presume that no thermal photons should be expected?

Comment: The question [Is there an equivalent of Rindler coordinates for an object in centripetal motion?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156278/is-there-an-equivalent-of-rindler-coordinates-for-an-object-in-centripetal-motio) looks relevant but has no answer. [This paper allegedly derives a metric for a rotating spacetime](http://cpb.iphy.ac.cn/fileup/PDF/20000503.pdf) though whether it is correct I can't say. This seems an obvious question and I'm surprised the answer isn't well known, but it seems not to be.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is, but [it is somewhat complicated](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Unruh_effect#Rotational_analog_of_the_Unruh_effect) since there is ambiguity of what constitutes a circularly accelerated coordinate system.

This paper, [On the physical meaning of the Unruh effect](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2525v3) by Akhmedov and Singleton derives a formula for the Unruh effect in circular motion. They find that the spectrum experienced is not Planckian and do not get a closed form equation for it, but the same effect is there. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1099) gives the temperature as $$T\approx \frac{\hbar a}{2\sqrt{3}ck_B}.$$ In the linear acceleration formula $2\sqrt{3}$ is replaced by $2\pi$.

(There is also [this paper showing a nonlinear dependency](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.11439); I have a feeling this result depends on using a different set of coordinates.)

Comment: there is also a japanese called Nakamura that has very solid arguments against the validity of the Fuller-Davies result. https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6258v1