# Radiation in Non-inertial Frame of Reference

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames

Consider some stationary charge in an inertial frame of reference.

Consider an observer accelerating with respect to that charge. Does the accelerating observer see radiation? It would be reasonable to assume so.

From what I've read, though I'm not too sure, this is called "Unruh Radiation," and apparently there is no experimental evidence of Unruh Radiation. Doesn't this violate our notion of classical electrodynamics? Within the context of Maxwell's equations, a stationary charge viewed from an accelerating frame is indistinguishable from an accelerating charge in a stationary frame, correct?

Could someone with expertise on the issue shed light on any misconceptions I might have, as well as present a solution to this issue?

Comment: For the case of uniform acceleration in the classical EM context, this might be helpful:  [The radiation of a uniformly accelerated charge is beyond the horizon: a simple derivation](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0506049)

Answer (score 0):

The main question seems to be a [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212147/unruh-radiation-in-a-rotating-frame). The short answer is yes, a rotating frame should observe radiation - although a human-sized object would need to be rotating so rapidly I don't think this can be observed experimentally.

Unruh radiation is predicted in quantum field theory, not classical physics. The paradox raised is resolved because everyone agrees which frames are accelerating and which are inertial. For example, when you spin around you know you are spinning and not the universe around you. Likewise, everyone else will agree with you. The reason is called "[Mach's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle)".